# Can someone tell me the internal working of random function in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, python-2.7

I am using python for more than 1 year. One question strike in my mind, how the random values are generated, there is some specific mechanism through which particular value should be selected by system that appears to be random to user. In all programming language how it is generated? Does all have the same mechanism?

Comment: Dunno about vanilla Python, but I'm pretty sure numpy uses something called a Mersenne Twister. Wikipedia will have plenty of information on generating random numbers.

Comment: It is [Mersenne Twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister) in python . You can reference in random module [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html)(line 9)!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/random.html

Answer (score 1):

Usually the OS provides a source of (pseudo) random data. For example on Linux there are `/dev/urandom` and `/dev/random`.

Some random functions in programming languages use that, other are based on a seed value and generate more or less reproducible values from it.

The `random` module in Python used a seeded approach. For use-cases that require more randomness use the `secrets` module. I uses the OS random sources.